# Display inline image list load dynamically

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to load a list of image, inside a div, and put them in horizontal (to be scrolled)

the problem is I can't load them one next to the other keeping the dimension of image in percentage.

CSS:

```
 @charset"UTF-8";
 /* CSS Document */
 #collectionContainer {
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     right:0px;
     bottom:15%;
     height:auto;
     width:auto;
     overflow-y: hidden;
     overflow-x: scroll;
 }
 #collectionContainer ul {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style-type: none;
 }
 #collectionContainer ul li {
     display:inline-block;
     float:left;
 }
```

page:

```
    <div id="collectionContainer">
        <ul>
            <? $dir='content/collection/' .$_GET[ 'collSea']. '/'; 
$dh=opendir($dir); 
while (false !==( $filename=r eaddir($dh))) { 
if ($filename !=="." && $filename !==".." ){ 
if (pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=="jpg" ){ ?>
            <li>
                <img width="auto" height="100%" src="content/collection/<? echo($_GET['collSea']); ?>/<? echo($filename); ?>" />
            </li>
            <?  } } } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: not dinamically, its  'dynamically'

Comment: sorry for really bad english....

Comment: @ user3785560: not like that, me also not 100% in english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
li {
    width: 1000%;
}
```

It should work!

Comment: I however suggest you to set the above width dynamically, using Javascript, so that you won't have excess space to the right.

Comment: Thank you...=) i solve it changing the main div width to 1000% and as you told me, i adjust it via javaScript..